# How to fix this error Undefined offset: 1 in line 178

Tags: php

Database:

```
$data = $_POST["input1"];       
$data = explode(",", $data)[1]; // line 178
$decoded_image = base64_decode($data);
$temp_name = 'img/'.md5(time().rand().time()).".png";
file_put_contents($temp_name, $decoded_image);
// Store this $file to table.
$file = basename($temp_name);
```

How to fix this error

Comment: The post parameter doesn't have any commas in it, so `explode()` is returning an array with only one element. Why are you trying to use the second element?

Comment: It means the array created using `explode()` doesn't have that index (1). In other words, it doesn't have a minimum of two items.

Comment: the post parameter is the base64 of the canvas image

Comment: `base64` doesn't put a comma in the data, why are you using `explode()`?

Comment: ahhh okay sir what is your suggestion to make this code runs? is it possible i replace str?

Comment: Sounds like you can just remove line 178?

Answer (score 2):

1 index of $data variable so right index with variable iike this

`$data = explode(",", $data[1]);`